# MySQL syntax error on table 'tbl_maticula'

Tags: java, mysql, syntax

I'm having a syntax issue with my SQL table. The error on the page says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tbl_matricula' at line 1

The table has the following lines in it:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_matricula (
datasituacao date NOT NULL,
idatividade int(11) NOT NULL,
idaluno int(11) NOT NULL,
defsituacao int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (idaluno)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The stacktrace of the error:

```
INFO  com.cs.sig.framework.model.db.DBConnectorFactory [68]: CREATING DIRECT DBCONNECTION     (NOT USING POOL).
ERROR org.apache.jsp.admin.matriculaList_jsp [302]: You have an error in your SQL syntax;         check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use     near 'tbl_matricula' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL     syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax     to use near 'tbl_matricula' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2620)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2570)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1474)
at com.cs.sig.framework.model.db.DBQuery.execute(DBQuery.java:82)
at com.cs.sig.framework.model.definition.DynamicDefinition.loadWithQuery(DynamicDefinition.java:223)
at com.cs.sig.framework.model.definition.DynamicDefinition.<init>(DynamicDefinition.java:105)
at com.cs.sig.shared.definition.DSituacao.<init>(DSituacao.java:26)
at com.cs.sig.shared.definition.DSituacao.getInstance(DSituacao.java:19)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.matriculaList_jsp._jspService(matriculaList_jsp.java:182)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone help me with this? I'm beginner so... sorry if there's anything wrong with the question.

Comment: The problem is not the SQL statement.  It works fine at SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a434a).  Perhaps there are some other characters sneaking into the statement in your code.  (Also, I removed the sql-server tag because error references MySQL.)

Comment: Okay. I'm gonna try to track if there's any character out of place.

Comment: Should that comma before PRIMARY KEY be there?

Comment: I got some help yesterday. I was advised to change the column "idauluno" for just "id", and exclude the space between "tbl_matricula" and "(". Nothing changed, though. Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. It was on mysql workbench configuration.

I have run the script "tables.sql" in the Terminal as well as the others .sql files the system requires and it has worked really fine.